# Creating a Rolling Cipher using a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

I'm trying to write a function that is supposed to take a string like "abcd" and move the letter up or down by a certain number.

rolling_cipher("abcd", 1) ➞ "bcde"

Here is my code so far:

```
import string


def rolling_cipher(String, num):
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    print(letters)

    String = String.index(string)


rolling_cipher("abcd", 2)
```

Comment: Please update your question with a question.

Comment: `abcd` does not contain `e`. How by moving does `e` come?

Comment: First of all, I would caution against using String as a variable name when you also import the string module.  Secondly, think about what you want to do inside your function.  Finally, look at the edge conditions. If the incoming letter is an 'a' and the shift is -2, what result do you want, also if the incoming letter is 'z' and the shift is +2, what result do you want?  Update your code and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

def rolling_cipher(s, n):
    idx = ascii_lowercase.index(s)
    new_idx = (idx + n) % len(ascii_lowercase)
    l = new_idx + len(s) - len(ascii_lowercase)
    a1 = ascii_lowercase[new_idx: new_idx + len(s)]
    a2 = '' if l <= 0 else ascii_lowercase[: l]
    return a1 + a2
```

Examples:

```
>>> rolling_cipher('abcd', 3)
'defg'
>>> rolling_cipher('rst', 6)
'xyz'
>>> rolling_cipher('rst', 8)
'zab'
>>> rolling_cipher('rst', 33)
'yza'
```

You might alternatively want to use `deque`:

```
from collections import deque
from string import ascii_lowercase

def rolling_cipher(s, n):
    d = deque(ascii_lowercase)
    d.rotate(-ascii_lowercase.index(s) - n)
    return ''.join(list(d)[:len(s)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's a one-liner that will do the trick:

```
import string

l = string.ascii_lowercase
s = 'eggs'

''.join(l[(l.rindex(i) + n) % 26] for i in s)
```

Output:

```
n = 1
>>> 'fhht'

n = 5
>>> 'jllx'

n = 100  # Same as -4
>>> 'acco'

n = -26
>>> 'eggs'
```

And, if you want to wrap it in a function:

```
def rolling(s, n) -> str:
    """Caesar cipher.
    
    Args:
        s (str): String to be encrypted.
        n (int): Shift value.
        
    Returns:
        Encrypted string.
    
    """
    return ''.join(l[(l.rindex(i) + n) % 26] for i in s)
```

Output:

```
rolling('eggs', -5)
>>> 'zbbn'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this

```
def foo(str:string, idx:int):
    print(string.ascii_lowercase[idx: len(str) + idx])
```

Comment: I’m honestly not sure how this is supposed to work.  1) `string`, the builtin library is not a data type, and 2) `str` the data type is being overwritten.  Additionally, the `ascii_lowercase` string is being sliced.  Why?  Please add some explanation around the code being presented.

Comment: @S3DEV you will debug or check it if u don't understand. Actually, I think it's clear.

Comment: The `str` type is being overwritten, and `string` is a library, not a type.

Comment: just check it https://onlinegdb.com/H17o9f9UP

Comment: What about `foo('xyz', 3)`? Or `foo('abc', 100)`?